# Regex: remove everything except the letters and separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using replace statements to replace certain parts of a string. I think my code is a bit over the top and could be simplified:

```js
const locales = 'fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5'
locales = locales.replace('-','_')
locales = locales.replace(';q=','')
locales = locales.replace(/[0-9]/g,'')
locales = locales.replace('.','')
```

In the end, I want to remove everything except for the locale from the string using regex and replace `-` with `_`. I would like the final string to look like this:

```js
'fr_CH, fr, en, de, *'
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: 3 of the replacements are the same. Could always replace(/[0-9\-.]/,'') then the separate one replace('-','_'). Or can use a callback. You imply first by non global, but I'm sure you don't mean this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A carefully chosen regular expression can strip out the weightings in one replacement. A second switches the hyphens `-` for underscores `_`

```
const locales = 'fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5';
newLocales = locales.replace(/;q=\d*\.\d*/g,'').replace(/-/g,'_');
console.log(newLocales);   //  fr_CH, fr, en, de, *
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace and search for two small characters and possible following dash and some more upper case characters or a star.

```js
const
    locales = 'fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5',
    parts = locales
        .replace(/-/g, '_')
        .match(/[a-z]{2}_*[A-Z]*|\*/g)
        .join(', ');

console.log(parts);
```

An even shorter approach which relaces all parts after semicolon (inclusive) until following comma without converting/matching to an array an joining back to a string.

```js
const
    locales = 'fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5',
    parts = locales
        .replace(/-/g, '_')
        .replace(/;[^,]+/g, '')

console.log(parts);
```